# Get value returned from an event listener inside the function it's assigned in

Tags: javascript, function, events, return, indexeddb

I want to be able to get a value returned from an event listener callback which is assigned inside a function, so that I can return the same value from the main function and store it in a variable. Consider this example:

```js
function receiveThenReturn() {
    request = something.request();
    request.onsuccess = function () {
        return request.result;
    }
}

let value = receiveThenReturn();
```

I have a `JavaScript` function which sends a request to the `IndexedDB` API and receives data. I want these data to be returned from the function which I'm able to call so that calling `let quizzes = readQuizzes()` directly returns the received data, but the problem is that the return statement is inside another function which is an Event Listener for `onsuccess`. I want the function to send the request, receive and return its results. This is my actual code:

```js
function readQuizzes(error = defaultError) {
    let transaction = database.transaction([quizStoreName], "readonly");
    let quizStore = transaction.objectStore(quizStoreName);
    let request = quizStore.openCursor();

    request.onerror = error;
    let quizzes = []
    request.onsuccess = function (e) {
        let cursor = e.target.result;

        if (cursor) {
            let quiz = cursor.value;
            quizzes.push(quiz);
            cursor.continue();
        } else { return quizzes; }
    }
}
```

My purpose is to be able to store the variable inside the callback function into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
async function receiveThenReturn() {
    request = something.request();
    request.onsuccess = await function () {
        return request.result;
    }
return request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here I made an example of what you are looking for:

```js
const addEventListener = function(element, event, functionToDo){
   element.addEventListener(event, function(event){
      functionToDo(event, "some other parametres");
   });
}

const btn = document.getElementById("someBtn");
addEventListener( btn, "click", function(e, message){
  alert(message);
  console.log( e );
});
```

```html
<button id="someBtn">Click me To fire the Event!</button>
```